# Daily rolling log file in Websphere Liberty (16.0.0.4-WS-LIBERTY-CORE)

Tags: websphere-liberty

How to create a daily rolling log file in Websphere Liberty? I want the name of the log file to have YYYYMMDD format.

Currently I'm only able to limit the max file size, max file and a static naming of messages.log and disable consolelog.

```
 <logging consoleLogLevel="OFF" maxFileSize="1" maxFiles="3" messageFileName="loggingMessages.log"/>
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere Liberty does not currently have the ability to schedule log file rotation like traditional WAS.  You can request this feature using the [RFE site](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/help/submit-rfe/).

Alternatively, you could use an approach like Bruce mentioned - perhaps using a cron job to restart the server at midnight.

You might also consider configuring Liberty's [binary logging](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/twlp_confHPEL.html).  This will create a binary log file that can be queried to produce actual log files (with filtering options, etc.).  It does have some time-based options.  More info [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.zseries.doc/ae/cwlp_HPELOverview.html).

Hope this helps, Andy

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the answer you want, but if you restart the server it will roll the log.

Comment: yes... it works... but not intuitive enough... can create a shell script to backup the logs and restart the server at midnight